# How to return the list of current data after making changes to the cache?

Tags: java, spring, caching

After any crud operation with cache data, I get not actual values in returned List of all entities (method getAllProxyConfigurations). 
Why can this happen and how to fix it?

```
   @Cacheable("configuration")
    public List<MySomeConfiguration> getAllProxyConfigurations() {
        return repository.getAllConfigurations();
}

   @Cacheable(value = "configuration", key = "#root.target.getConfigurationById(#id).serverId")
    public MySomeConfiguration getConfigurationById(Long id) {
...
   return configuration;
}

 @CachePut(value = "configuration", key = "#configuration.serverId", condition = "#result.id != null")
    public MySomeConfiguration addOrUpdateConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
   return configuration;
}

   @Cacheable(value = "configuration", key = "#serverId")
    public MySomeConfiguration getConfigurationByServerId(String serverId) {...
   return configuration;
}

   @CacheEvict(value = "configuration", key = "#root.target.getConfigurationById(#id).serverId")
    public void deleteConfigurationById(Long id) {
...
}
```

Comment: Looks like the same _configuration_ cache, but `getAllProxyConfigurations()` uses a different key (the default key since no arguments).  Perhaps the CRUD methods can evict the default key so `repository.getAllConfigurations()` will be invoked.

Comment: @AndrewS I'm sorry, but I didn't understand you completely. What do I need to do?

Comment: `SimpleKey.EMPTY` is the default cache key  used for a method with no parameters.  For the crud methods, add something like `@CacheEvict(value = "configuration", key = "SimpleKey.EMPTY")`.  (I'm not sure of the exact SpEL.)

Comment: @AndrewS as an option, but not in this case.
I cannot use it in other methods, for example: xxxById, where the id key and it is different from serverId and the same irrelevant data is received.
It looks like the solution is to create my custom keyGenerator.